# <ul> display inline-block not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

My jsFiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/r1s6651y/1/

I am not able to get Navigation with Numerals to be aligned horizontally.

I have applied `display : inline-block` for upper `ul` but still the next menu item begins on the second line.

Any clues ?

It should be stacked as :

```
1111111    22222222

AAAAAAAAAAAAA

BBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Apply the display inline to the `li` rather than the `ul` :)

Comment: All is working fine, you need to write inline-block to `<li>`elements

Comment: @PXgamer Doesnt work .. it still stacked vertically

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I tried - it doesnt work

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1s6651y/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have `li` with `width: 100%;` and then expect them to align next to eachother. Ofcourse they naturally fall to 2 lines instead of 1, they're inline elements after all *(Think of it like this: the `<p>` tag is also "inline" bu default. When the text in a `<p>` is too long, the text "breaks" to a new line. As will your `li` when it is set to be inline)*. You also want the `li` to next to eachother, not the `ul` which is what contains the `li`. So apply the `display: inline-block;` to the (correct) `li` elements

```
    ul#myRow li {
      width: auto; //could also be set to 50%  if it's just 2 li elements
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: with width auto - the menu are now disproportionate  - based on what is written in the <a> - how to have utilize full width of the screen - so that they occupy 50%-%50% of the screen

Comment: Then set the width to 50%? :) "width: 50%;"

Comment: the moment you give 50% - it wraps and goes to the next line

Comment: I did some research and found the answer! Inline elements have a natural space between them. First, you need to remove the padding on the li, and use that padding on the <a> inside the li instead. That way, the 30px padding wont be added on top of the li 50% width.  Then we have the problem that inline elements actually have a weird behaviour where extra space is added. the solution is to remove the white-space in the HTML between the tags. like this: <li>"content</li><li>"content"</li>. Just make usre the end-tag of the first li and the beginning tag of the second li are next to eachother

Answer (score 2):

Two things.  As already noted, you want the `li` items to be `display:inline`.  You also need to remove the `width:100%` from the `li`s of `#myRow`.  Then it will collapse and display inline as long as the container is wide enough for them (otherwise it will wrap).

```css
li {
  background: #00945f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #016e39;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  height: 62px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul#myRow li {
  display:inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <ul id="myRow" class="row">
    <li>
      <a href="" class="active">11111111</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">2222222</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="row">
    <li>
      <a href="">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Man, you do some mistakes.
I fixed it at: https://jsfiddle.net/r1s6651y/4/

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #00945f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #016e39;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but I think they only wanted the top 2 inline (as per their pictogram)

Comment: I noticed after, but the important thing is he learn how to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

put a `class` on the `li` you want horizontal, then add css `display: inline`

```css
.horiz {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul id="myRow" class="row">
    <li class="horiz">
      <a href="" class="active">11111111</a>
    </li>
    <li class="horiz">
      <a href="">2222222</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="row">
    <li>
      <a href="">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Why would you do that and not just: `li { display: inline-block; }`?

Comment: Cause they only want it on the top 2 `li`'s (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @Peurr because if you just put `inline` or `inline-block` on the general `li` element, then all the `li` would be displayed horizontally within their `ul`, and OP wants AAAA and BBBB to be stacked vertically, and only the numbers to be horizontal. Some of the other answers use `#myRow` to select the horizontal `li` which works but when i was writing the answer, i didnt see the `id` at first, so i just used a `class`